# why do I need redux in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to find out why do I need redux if RN already have state, I can use state as I want as action or change something.

So why would I need it?

Comment: Redux is used to separate your state management logic from your view logic. It's  kind of (but not really) like MVC but for react

Answer (score 7):

Redux provides a "shared state" that every component can access. For example, you may have found that a parent component needs to be aware of the state of a child component. You can resolve this in React alone by passing down a method as props to the child but this isn't a pattern you want to be repeating again and again, especially as your component structure becomes more complex and hierarchical. Redux provides an elegant solution. For small apps though, it's probably not necessary.